# SonarQube upgrade from 3.5.1 to 4.2

Tags: sonarqube-4.0

I have upgraded sonarQube from 3.5.1 to 4.2, When I run sonar from teamcity, Count of violation issues has changed for the projects, Is it an acceptable behavior?